# How is the wildcard * interpreted as a command?

Tags: bash, wildcards

I know how `*` is interpreted in commands like `ls` for example. But when trying to run `*` as a command the shell tries to execute the first file or directory in your working directory. Why is this? How does the shell understand `*`?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Unlike in some other operating systems, in Unixes, it's the shell that expands filename wildcards. It expands parameter expansions and globs first, then uses the (now) first word as the name for the command to run.

This is also why files named with a leading dash can be troublesome: a glob like `*` will expand to the file names, and a name starting with a dash may be taken as an option. (The scary example being that a file called `-r` in the working directory would make `rm *` remove everything recursively...)

Usually, one wouldn't use `*` as the first item on any command line, though, so having the first file determine the command to run in that case isn't likely to cause problems.

Comment: I think this example misses an important point out, that filename expansion is not subject to further field splitting, unlike parameter expansion, so filenames with spaces are still safe.

Comment: OK, so I think I misunderstood how the * work in the first place. I thought that it is a common syntax used in Linux commands. But, if I understood your answer correctly, then filename expansion is a shell feature not a command feature. So what happened is that * got replaced by all file or directory names in PWD but when the shell tried executing the first one it produced the error I saw.

Comment: @osmak, yeah, it's a shell feature on Unixes. Easier that way, so each and every program doesn't have to implement it. Though of course programs like `find` know how to expand similar patterns, too (e.g. `file -name "*.txt"`)

Comment: @osmak That is a correct understanding.

Comment: @MichaelHomer, yeah, it wasn't really an example on running `*` as a command, but really I can't think of a sane example using `*` is the sole item on a command line...  Probably not a security/safety issue either since, well, it's not that often someone would just run `*` as a command, even by accident.

Comment: @ilkkachu how is it different in the find command? does it have its own implementation or interpretation of *?

Comment: @osmak The `find` command can't let the shell expand the glob as that would expand to things in the wrong directory. Therefore, `find` takes the glob as a string, and then uses (probably) the `fnmatch()` C library routine to perform the actual globbing at the correct path(s).

Comment: Thanks guys you have been very helpful. Can you please recommend a read or a tutorial that explains this stuff in details.

Comment: A file named `-r` is bad, but one named `-rf` is even worse.